# How to Print Scrapy Depth

Tags: python, scrapy

So I'm scraping through a site and am looking for a specific link in the site. If I start on the home page I want to see how far from the original page the spider got before it found the link

```
linksonpage = response.css('a::attr(href)').getall()

        for i in linksonpage:
            link = response.urljoin(i)

            if link == goallink:
                print('found the goal link')

            elif:
                yield scrapy.Request(link)
```

Linkdepth is currently set to 10 as a setting, but if it finds the link before it goes 10 out, i want to know how far it had to travel to get there.

Is there something like a 'link depth' variable that scrapy has inherently that i can call about where in the process it is or do i have to make a counter?

Answer (score 2):

I am foolish. It's just  response.meta['depth']

so you can set that as a variable.